# Access each element of series stored as a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, series, logical-operators

I want to perform a logical operation on each element of my series which is stored as a list. I have written the following code. However, it shows the error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Here is the code I have written:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_new           = pd.read_excel (r'file_name.xlsx')

columns = df_new.columns
jun = []
for col in columns[1:]:
    jun.append(df_new[col]/84)
for i in range(0,300):
    if jun[i]==1:
        jun.append(jun[i])
```

I am trying to debug, and I guess its the last 3 lines which cause the error. I don't know how to access each element from the series stored as a list. That is why the above-mentioned error pops. Please, help me understand the mistake.

Comment: Add a sample of what is in file_name.xlsx

Comment: Do you have `300` columns? If so, the fix would be `(jun[i]==1).all()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare all values in a colum using df.loc :

In code below if value in colum 1 is == 0, will be replaced for 'Value is 0', also you can put the result in another colum.

```
import pandas as pd

df1.loc[(df1.Col1 == '0'), 'Col1'] = 'Value is 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/) will help you :

```
import xlrd
path = ("file_name.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

print(sheet.ncols,sheet.nrows)

for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
for i in range(sheet.ncols): 
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing `jun[i]==1` you are comparing an entire column with 1 and you are getting a `pandas.core.series.Series` which cannot be evaluated in your `if` statement: `if jun[i]==1:`, to fix you can do:

```
if (jun[i]==1).all():
```